# Continuity at the origin of $f(x,y)$ given by $0$ there, and $\frac{\sqrt{|x||y|}}{|x|+|y|}$ elsewhere

Tags: continuity

> Define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by
>   \begin{equation*}
> f(x,y) := \begin{cases}
> \frac{\sqrt{|x||y|}}{|x|+|y|} & \textit{if} \; \; (x,y)\neq (0,0) \\
> 0 & \textit{if} \; \; (x,y) = (0,0)
> \end{cases}.
> \end{equation*}
>   Determine if $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$.

**My attempt.**

$f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ if:

1. $f(0,0)$ exists
2. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$ exists
3. $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y) = f(0,0)$.

If the limit is approached along the line $y = cx$, then
\begin{equation*}
f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{|x||y|}}{|x|+|y|} = \frac{\sqrt{|x|\times c|x|}}{|x|+c|x|} = \frac{\sqrt{c}|x|}{|x|(1+c)} = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{1+c},
\end{equation*}
so $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{c}}{1+c}$, which depends on $c$, thereby contradicting the uniqueness of limits which means the limit does not exist. Hence, $f$ is NOT continuous at $(0,0)$.

> Is this correct? If not, any help would be great.

Comment: This is correct but you have to take $c>0$.

Comment: Right because of the square root thanks!!!